# Jquery to disable document zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to disable document zooming in my web page.

I'm creating a web page for laptop Touch Screens that are running on Windows 8 this web page contains a pictures inside a dragabble divs ... the user drag it and drop it in a container then the application should let him/her zoom-in & out the image using(fingers or mouse scroll) ... every thing is cool.
but, the problem is if the image didn't recognize directly the pinch (to zoom) or the user put his fingers outside the image the document starts to (zoom-in & zoom-out)

what i need is to disable the document zooming using JQuery or css. please help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent pinch to zoom on your document you need to add meta tags to your html head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: don't work i think that we can use this only for mobile browsers and i need this for all touchscreens.

Comment: Question requests jQuery javascript. This meta tag does not work on normal browsers on touch screen computers.